# Fixed MAC addresses on Windows EC2 machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

On Windows machines that we own it's possible to change a MAC address to a pre-assigned value. But is it possible to set the MAC address on EC2 Windows machines to a pre-assigned value?

Here is the problem:

We provide a virtual lab/training/evaluation environment that runs off Amazon EC2. Every so often a customer wants to run licensed software (that they own!) in the cloud, but the licensing component requires a fixed MAC address to exist.

But it's unclear what happens in EC2 if we tweak with the MAC address, especially after a reboot or snapshot of the machine. One big issue I see is that if we take a snapshot of a machine with a fixed MAC, and then launch multiple copies of it, then each copy will, in theory, have the same MAC address. Obviously a routing issue.

But still, it's unclear what happens or if the underlying virtualization stack simply generates random MACs every time a machine is launched.

Of-course, I would love to hear about other workarounds if you have ideas..

Comment: uh, mac-address, machine-name are still a pain in EC2.

Comment: @SimonatLabSlice-com  - did you find a solution to this? I"m facing the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no good workaround here. EC2 does not allow any manipulation of the MAC address on an instance.

Comment: can't elastic network interfaces solve the problem?  or would there be an issue if it is not the primary interface?  I don't know if the software will look at the right mac adress if the elastic one is secondary.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html

Answer (score 17):

You can use an EC2 instance in a VPC and attach an Elastic Network Interface to it.

ENI is like an additional network card that have fixed IP address (internal and external) and fixed MAC address.

[More about ENI in AWS site](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html).

Comment: Yes, but while it is static and be reassigned to instances as needed, you cannot SET the MAC...the ENI still creates a new random one from scratch.